# Did I make a mistake? Checking for independent events

Tags: probability, independence

I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong. Say we have a deck of 52 cards, and we have the event `Q = pull a Queen` and `Event H = pull a Hearts`, I want to figure out of these two events are independent.

$P(Q) = \frac{4}{52}$ and $P(H) = \frac{13}{52}$

I'm aware that if they are independent, $P(Q\cap H) = P(Q)\cdot P(H) = P(H)\cdot P(Q|H)$. Since a heart could potentially be a queen, that would be $P(H\cap Q) = \frac{1}{52}$, as such: $$P(Q\mid H) \cdot P(H)  = P(H\cap Q) \cdot \frac{1}{P(H)} \cdot P(H)= \frac{1}{52}$$

Now since $P(H)\cdot P(Q) = \frac{1}{52}\cdot \frac{13}{52} = \frac{13}{52^2} \neq \frac{1}{52}$ we can conclude that they are not independent.

Am I doing this right, because I have a feeling I'm overcomplicating it and messed up..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your mistake is where you wrote $\frac{1}{52} \cdot \frac{13}{52}$, which doesn't match what you wrote earlier.

Comment: Multiply $P(Q) = \frac{4}{52}$ and $P(H) = \frac{13}{52}$ and you get the right answer.

Comment: @Joe ah right, thanks! but I don't understand. If that's the case, then $P(H)\cdot P(Q) = \frac{1}{52}$ which would indicate that they are independent. But how can they be independent if a heart can be a queen (or vice versa)?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor hey Robert, mind checking my reply to Joe?

Comment: Independent is not the same thing as "mutually exclusive".  For mutually exclusive things, if you know one happened, then you know the other did not.  For independent things, knowing that one thing happened tells you nothing about whether the other one did.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor oh wow, I guess I got that concept confused then. I will read up on it in more detail, thank you!

Comment: @RobertTheTutor PS: If you wish to write this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: To emphasize, "*knowing that one thing happened tells you nothing about whether the other one did*" is not just saying that it knowing the one happened you still might or might not have the other happen, that it is possible both happen, one of them at a time, or neither... the condition is far stronger.  It is saying that knowing one thing happened does not influence your expectation for the probability that the other happened... that is to say $\Pr(A\mid B) = \Pr(A)$.  Consider as an example of dependent events the event that you pull a Queen versus the event you pull a face card.

Comment: @JMoravitz I've just read up on independent events and I'm even more confused :P. It says "In probability, we say two events are independent if knowing one event occurred doesn't change the probability of the other event." but in my case, if I know that I pulled a Queen out, and if that queen happens to be a heart, my probability of pulling a heart is decreased?

Comment: First, your question was phrased as considering only the first card being pulled.  "*If I pulled a queen and it happened to be a heart*" then we know the first card is a heart... it changed the probability to $1$.  That is to say, $\Pr(H\mid Q\cap H)=1$.  Do not confuse this with the related problem of pulling a first card, asking if it was a queen, and then pulling a second card and asking if it was a heart.  That said, for the second problem it will *still* be independent and your complaint is irrelevant since you forgot to consider also what happens if the first card was *not* a heart.

Comment: @JMoravitz So if I understand this right, since we do not know if the first card is a queen AND a heart or just a queen, we need to consider it being just a queen and thus the probablity of pulling a heart does not change..? I don't understand why, since if it is indeed a heart, it influences the probability of the second pull being a heart directly, since the number of hearts left are 12 instead of 13...?

Comment: @JMoravitz this for some reason reminds me of the monty hall problem I saw in a movie once :P

Comment: That is to say, letting $Q_1,H_1,H_2$ be the events of pulling a queen on the first draw, pulling a heart on the first draw, and pulling a heart on the second draw when pulling two cards in sequence without replacement... while yes it is true that $\frac{12}{51}=\Pr(H_2\mid Q_1\cap H_1)<\Pr(H_2)=\frac{13}{52}$ it is also true that $\frac{13}{51}=\Pr(H_2\mid Q_1\cap H_1^c)>\Pr(H_2)$.  If you were to do the calculations, you'd have $\frac{1}{52}\cdot \frac{12}{51}+\frac{3}{52}\cdot\frac{13}{51}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{13}$, proving the independence of $Q_1$ and $H_2$

Comment: Worded another way... Given that the first card was a queen, let us consider the question of what the probability is that the second card is a heart.  Well... it should be the same answer as asking what the probability is that the second card is a spade, right?  There is no difference between the two problems after all.  Similarly for diamond or club.  Since it has to be one of these four and since they should all be equally likely, we see that $\Pr(H_2\mid Q_1)=\frac{1}{4}=\Pr(H_2)$, again proving their independence

Comment: @JMoravitz it clicked now, thanks so much. Please do add this as an official answer if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emphasize and clarify some points,

Mutually Exclusive events are those satisfying $A\cap B=\emptyset$, that is to say it is impossible for an outcome to be in both events simultaneously.  Take for an example "drawing a spade as the first card" versus "drawing a heart as the first card."  Mutually exclusive events will as a result satisfy $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$ and also $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$.

Warning: $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$ is *not* enough to say that two events are mutually exclusive (*particularly in infinite contexts such as continuous distributions*) and also $\Pr(A\cup B)$ is in general *not* equal to $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$.  Instead, the always true identity is that $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$

---

Independent Events are those events satisfying $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$.  Equivalently, those events satisfying $\Pr(A\mid B)=\Pr(A)$, or equivalently $\Pr(B\mid A)=\Pr(B)$.  That is to say, independent events are those who knowledge (*only*) of whether one event has happened or not does not influence our expectation of the probability of whether the other event has happened.

Warning: $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is in general *not* equal to $\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$.  Instead, the always true identity is that $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B\mid A)$.  Also, be warned that pairwise independence of several events does not imply mutual independence of several events.  That is to say, it is possible that $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$ and $\Pr(A\cap C)=\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(C)$ and $\Pr(B\cap C)=\Pr(B)\cdot \Pr(C)$, that $A,B$ are independent, that $A,C$ are independent, and $B,C$ are independent, while having $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)\neq \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$, that $A,B,C$ are not mutually independent.

---

It is possible for two events to be independent and not mutually exclusive.  It is possible for two events to be dependent and mutually exclusive.  It is possible for two events to be dependent and not be mutually exclusive.

As for independent and mutually exclusive, this occurs only when one or both of the events occur with probability zero.

Altogether, this means that if $\Pr(A)>0$ and $\Pr(B)>0$ you have $A$ and $B$ independent implies that they are not mutually exclusive, and that $A$ and $B$ mutually exclusive implies that they are not independent.  Keep in mind they could still be neither.

---

On to the specific question about cards.  To recap the comments above, you are confusing two similar problems.  Letting $Q_i$ and $H_j$ be the events that the $i$'th card drawn is a queen and the $j$'th card drawn is a heart respectively for whatever integers $i,j$... the original question being asked was to consider drawing a single card and comparing the events $Q_1,H_1$.

We do have $\Pr(Q_1)=\dfrac{4}{52}$, that $\Pr(H_1)=\dfrac{13}{52}$ and $\Pr(Q_1\cap H_1)=\dfrac{1}{52}$.  We do have $\Pr(Q_1\cap H_1)=\Pr(Q_1)\Pr(H_1)$ thus proving their independence.

The other related but different question you were alluding to is that of comparing the events $Q_1,H_2$... that is we pull two cards in sequence without replacement and ask about the first card being a queen and the second card being a heart.  You voice your concern about how these could possibly be independent since if the first card happened to be the queen of hearts it would reduce the available number of hearts to be pulled for the second card.

That complaint is common, however you failed to account for the fact that the opposite also holds... that if you did *not* pull a queen of hearts as the first card that the number of available hearts did *not* decrease along with the total pool of cards and so the probability actually would be *increased* that the second card would be a heart.

Actually going through the calculations,

$$\Pr(Q_1\cap H_2)=\Pr(Q_1\cap H_1\cap H_2)+\Pr(Q_1\cap H_1^c\cap H_2)$$

$$ = \Pr(Q_1\cap H_1)\Pr(H_2\mid Q_1\cap H_1)+\Pr(Q_1\cap H_1^c)\Pr(H_2\mid Q_1\cap H_1^c)$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{52}\cdot\dfrac{12}{51}+\dfrac{3}{52}\cdot\dfrac{13}{51}=\dfrac{1}{52}=\dfrac{4}{52}\cdot\dfrac{13}{52}=\Pr(Q_1)\cdot\Pr(H_2)$$

This proves their independence.

Imprecise unqualified statements like "*When drawing without replacement, draws are not independent of each other*" can be incorrect, like shown here.  The individual *atomic* outcomes may well be dependent, but when looking at them as collections of events like here we find that the only way to be sure is to actually go through with the analysis.

Another faster way to verify their independence is to recall that $\Pr(H_2)=\Pr(H_2\mid Q_1)=\dfrac{1}{4}$ as the second card isn't any more or less likely to be a heart as it would be to be a spade or a club or diamond... since these four suits are just as likely to be the suit of the second card (*even if we were to condition on the first card being a queen*) it follows that the probability must be $\frac{1}{4}$, thus showing $\Pr(H_2)=\Pr(H_2\mid Q_1)$ thus proving $Q_1$ and $H_2$'s independence.

Comment: Amazing, that is awesome, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is a confusion of "independent" and "mutually exclusive."

If $Q$ and $H$ are "independent events", that means that knowing whether one happened does not affect the probability of the other one happening; it gives you no information.  Essentially, it is like "the price of tea in China", totally unrelated and irrelevant to the other thing.  An example would be the first roll of a die and the second roll of the die.

Another example would be pulling a card and getting a heart, versus pulling a card and getting a queen.  Note there is only ONE draw.  If you draw a queen, there is a 1/4 chance that it is a heart.  If you don't draw a queen, there is still a 1/4 chance that it is a heart.  Knowing only that you got a queen tells you nothing about whether it also happened to be a heart or not.

If you draw a card, and don't replace it, and make another draw, the probabilities usually shift, as when checking if the first card is a heart, then if the second card is a heart.  When drawing without replacement, draws are not always independent of each other, depending on what information is being looked at on each card.  But this problem has only one draw in the first place.  We are talking about two different details of a single draw, not different draws.

"Mutually exclusive events" cannot both happen.  So if you know one happened, then you know the other did not.  An example of this would be, when rolling a die only once, you cannot get a $2$ and a $3$ at the same time.  They are mutually exclusive outcomes.  If one of them happened, the other did not.  Note it is still possible that neither of them happen.

Choosing a face value and choosing a suit are independent events, and not mutually exclusive, since the queen of hearts exists, as you pointed out.

Comment: So I've read the following: "In probability, we say two events are independent if knowing one event occurred doesn't change the probability of the other event." but in my case, if I know that I pulled a Queen out, and if that queen happens to be a heart, my probability of pulling a heart is decreased isn't it?

Comment: @JakeDrone Added detail for you.  The probability of drawing a heart IF you were to draw AGAIN is definitely lower, but that's not what's being looked at here.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Be careful, what you just added in that last edit is incorrect.  Letting $Q_1$ be the event the first card is a queen and $H_2$ the event the second card is a heart were we to draw two cards in sequence without replacement, we do still have $Q_1,H_2$ are independent events, contrary to the untrained student's intuition.  "*When drawing without replacement, draws are not independent of each other*"  This statement needs strong clarification as otherwise it would lead to the wrong conclusion about the alluded to problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly evaluated $\mathsf P(Q)=1/13, \mathsf P(H)=1/4,$ and $\mathsf P(Q\cap H)= 1/52$. $~\color{green}\checkmark$

Next you want to establish whether $\mathsf P(Q\cap H)\overset?=\mathsf P(Q)\mathsf P(H)$ when you know $\mathsf P(Q\cap H)=\mathsf P(Q\mid H)\mathsf P(H)$ and $\mathsf P(H)\neq 0$.

Therefore you just need to ascertain whether $\mathsf P(Q\mid H)\overset?=\mathsf P(Q)$.

Well, by definition, $\mathsf P(Q\mid H)~{=\dfrac{\mathsf P(Q\cap H)}{\mathsf P(H)}}$, so... .